# Difference betwen coated and uncoated formula guides for use on consumer products?

Tags: color, pantone, color-reproduction

We are looking for colors to be used on portable air conditioners. What is the difference between coated an uncoated formula guide as we choose a color for our product.

Comment: Im sorry I dont understand, based on reading your question, how this falls on interface-design and adobe tags??  Can you make an [edit] and explain please?

Answer (score 2):

The difference in the formula guides is how *that* color will appear when *that* ink is applied to a coated or uncoated stock. In general terms, ink on uncoated stock looks a bit less saturated than on coated stock. But be aware the Pantone Formula Guides are references **stock** (paper) not other substrates such as metal or plastic. Pantone Formula Guides may be the wrong guides to use if you are using a different substrate.

In terms of "portable air conditioners", you may need to determine the printing processes first. Pantone may be entirely inappropriate for the printing method being used. You may need to examine Toyo or FocolTone inks. Or speak to the product manufacturer to determine their capabilities for reproduction on the materials.